# Where are stored phonegap databases in Android or Iphone?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, database, cordova

I'm having troubles to find the SQLite databases that Phonegap creates on iPhone and Android.

 I've checked the /data folder but there aren't any there.
I know that the APIs are based in the W3C Web SQL Database Specification and W3C Web Storage API Specification, and in computer's browsers I can see them with the inspector. In Phonegap documentation it says that it creates as SQLite database but I can't find it in my android device and iPhone.
Does anyone know where PhoneGap creates the databases?

Thanks in advance,
Elkas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I did is easier and simpler. I did this for a single testing app and hope it will help you to.

Tiger ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/(version which you are testing)5.0/Applications/AADBB179-EC96-4020-910C-85CB01513C58 (yours will be different)/Library/Webkit/Databases/file__0/0000000000000001.db

Your file is 0000000000000001.db

Comment: Hi , I cant find 0000000000000001.db file in my Database Folder. Do you know why so ?

Answer (score 0):

~/Library/Safari/  or ~/Library/WebKit

Where ~ = the application directory.

Hope this helps. I do not have an actual device to check on at the moment.