# Filepath to the sqlite file in phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, sqlite, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm using phonegap and I can do all the normal transaction but wondered where sqlite file is generated with these records or as working internally.

Comment: What do you mean by "iternamente"?

Answer (score 0):

Hope You are looking for this

- [Please Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227110/android-where-is-sqlite-database-stored) to find db location in Android.
- [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765914/where-are-stored-phonegap-databases-in-android-or-iphone) to find db location in iOS.